# Haskell random numbers suddenly start to "converge" after months of running

Tags: haskell, random

I have a server program that randomly selects 10 from a group of network peers to accomplish a task. The code that generates the random indices of the peers is as follows:

```
indices = let index = getStdRandom $ randomR (0, number_of_peers - 1)
          in sequence $ replicate 10 index
```

The program has been running for months, generating thousands of `indices' each day, and has been working fine until yesterday, when I noticed that something has gone wrong: the random numbers generated seem to "converge" to a few repeating values (the result is that the corresponding network peers are heavily loaded).

To see the change, below is from the server log a few days ago:

```
peers selected: [55,47,80,74,183,85,04,33,72,58]
```

and the log from today's (as you can see, peer 53, 37 and 195 are repeatedly selected):

```
peers selected: [53,53,37,37,37,37,195,195,195,21]
```

The program is running on an x86_64 version of Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: i do believe that the proper way of handing generating multiple random numbers is to feed the seed of one into the next random computation, or at least using `newStdGen` (which is still kind of iffy).

Comment: In the case of grabbing a new seed every time, you're leaving things up to the system/environment.  But passing the seed off every time means you're relying on the haskell libraries and the math inside them.  At this point none of the actual cryptographic stuff is really handled by haskell.  this problem isn't a haskell problem, then, and more of an ubuntu problem.

Comment: @JustinL. According the the doc, the random generator used by getStdRandom is **single, implicit, and global**, and each call to getStdRandom will fetch it, use it, update it and return it, so I guess that is equivalent to explicit passing. But I do think this is a Linux problem.

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake.  ignore everything I said; getStdRandom is just the exact same as explicitly passing the seed.  in this case it probably isn't a linux problem because linux only comes into play at the start.

Comment: @JustinL. Combined MLCG used by `System.Random` hardly counts as cryptographic, as well as `stdGen` initialization using only current system time and process CPU time. But this convergence looks mighty strange indeed. FWIW, looking at the source code (and repeatedly calling `getStdGen` in a fresh GHCi session) shows that default initialization always creates `StdGen s1 s2` with s2 = 1, perhaps unintentionally, while the original L'Ecuyer paper suggests that both should be initialized with truly random numbers in a certain range.

Comment: If `number_of_peers` is 10, `indices` generates numbers between 0 and 10, yet your logs show "r37", "r195" (And where's the 'r' coming from?)  We're missing a step which might be worth investigating.

Comment: @ja. Sorry for the confusion, the code and the log was slightly modified to make the problem statement a little clearer. There are 200 peers in total, and the program randomly selects 10 out of them. `r' is the name of the peers.

Comment: Although it's preferable to look for a solution that doesn't consume so many file descriptors, you *can* increase the maximum file descriptor count using `ulimit -Sn 4096` or the like in bash shell (or script) and then run your server.  This can buy you some convenience while you're looking for a better solution.  There also a system-wide limit handled with `sysctl`, and a way to modify per-user limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  More info at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/ and lots of other places.

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys Actually I did the ulimit trick soon after the problem was found. This bug teaches me never to jump to conclusions too quickly.

Comment: @Aufheben If you've solved the problem, you should post an answer and accept it. That way, other users can see that the problem is solved, and it'll stop showing up on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After investigation this turns out to be an embarrassing bug of my own: the root user on this server has a limit of maximum open files of 1024, which is unexpectedly low (but I heard that this is the default on Ubuntu). When the server program has too many open sockets, some part of the system starts to reject the peers, making their status 'inactive'. The actual 'indices' is:

```
indices = let index = getStdRandom $ randomR (0, M.size active - 1) in
              sequence $ replicate (n * 2) index
```

I'm sorry if this question is causing any trouble or confusion. I'll try to post more prudently next time.